# How to call overriden function from child in java?

Tags: java, oop, overloading

I want to make an interface and from user point of view i want it to look clean and they can write their code with this syntax.

```
public class child extends parent {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   }
 }
```

Main is in the parent but how can one call a overriden function in parent.
Also i don't want the name "child" to be mandatory so i can't call it directly.

PS:this is the run function i want to override.

```
public class parent{
public static void main(String[] args) {
  run();
   }
 }
```

Comment: _Main is in the parent but how can one call a overwritten function in parent_ please elaborate

Comment: I suppose you are confusing between main() function and some random Main class that you are referring to. In general when it comes to inheritance you cannot call a derived class's overridden function from a base class. In that case what you do is create a base class pointer and make it point to derived class object. In that case when you use the base class pointer to invoke the function the overriden derived classs

Comment: It is good practise to have an uppercase first letter for classname, eg. `Child` and `Parent`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Call Parent#run() from child or call Child#run() from parent?

Comment: I want to create a template class but its childs have one uniqe function each and class names differ so i referance them with their parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Parent and run `abstract`. Abstract for a class means that this class cannot be directly instantiated, but can be instantiated if there is a subclass. Abstract for a method means that the method is defined in the abstract class, but is not implemented in the abstract class. Instead subclasses must provide an implementation of the abstract method or declare themselves to be abstract.

```
public abstract class Super {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Super s = new Sub();
        s.main(); 
    }

    public abstract void run();

    public void main() {
        System.out.println("Calling sub class's implementation of run");
        // The super class does not know the implementation of run
        // but it does know that there must be an implementation to use.
        run();
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }

}

class Sub extends Super {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("sub class implementation of run");
    }

}
```

Comment: It's great but is there a way to abstract the name Sub and not using it in Super at all?

Comment: Do mean for the constuctor statement -- `Super s = new Sub();`? No, when constructing an instance of type Super you must know the direct subclass. But once the object is constructed you may pass if around to different methods as type Super.

Answer (score 1):

to call overridden function of perent class use..
 `super.run();`
**EX:**

```
public class child extends parent {   
  @Override
  public void run() {  
  super.run(); 
   }
  }
```

what i get from you is ..**u want to call child function from parent class**..
For that is seams like a normal class function coz there  is only relationship b/w **parent-to-child** no relation in **child-to-parent**
So u just make object of child and then call function of child class...
So your main of parent class may be look like this..

```
          public static void main(String[] args) {
          new child().run();            
    }
```

Comment: isn't your example calls run from parent? I want to call child's run from parent inside main function.

Comment: That doesn't sound correct. You want to call the run() method in child from within parent's main function?

Answer (score 0):

To call an overwritten function in the parent user something like one of these:

```
super.run();

((parent) this).run();
```

Comment: That second way won't work. The JVM will just look at the virtual method table for the object, see that it an instance of child and choose the child implementation over parent implementation.

Comment: Useful syntax when a class implements different interfaces. Not useful here like you said.

Comment: I think I'm going to sound pedantic here, but I don't think such syntax would help in java. Since each class can only have one implementation of a particular method there should never be confusion about which method to run. I know C++ has multiple inheirtance. There such syntax might be useful. That is, a sub class extends both A and B (which have an identical method signature). Thus, the subclass will need to make the compiler aware of which method to use. eg. `((A)this).method();`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to call the run() function defined in the parent?

```
public class child extends parent 
{
  @Override
  public void run() 
  {
    super.run();    // call parent's run() function
    this.doStuff(); // call child's additional functionality
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand correctly. But parent can't know  if, where and how it's protected/public methods will be overriden so it cant call the overridden implementations.

If you have to do it, you probably got your class hierarchy design wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can call super(Parent) class methods using 'super' keyword. Like this.

`public class child extends parent {
  @Override

 public void run() { 
super.run();
   } 
 }`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are confusing between main() function and some random Main class that you are referring to. In general when it comes to inheritance you cannot call a derived class's overridden function from a base class. In that case what you do is create a base class pointer and make it point to derived class object. In that case when you use the base class pointer to invoke the function the overriden derived classs' function gets called.

I am not sure if I answered you entirely..

This might help you.. -> http://www.oodesign.com/dependency-inversion-principle.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I am answering your question right. From what I understood is you are trying to do some thing like calling child's run from Parent. If that is the case below is the code snippet to do it.

```
 public abstract class Parent{

    public abstract void run();

    public void mainMethod(){
      //This automatically calls run from child
       run();
    }
  }
```

And your child implementation is like as shown below.

```
public class child extends parent {
  @Override
  public void run() {

   //Do the stuff you want to

   }
 }



public class MainClass{

    public static void main(String args[]){
       Parent obj = new Child();
       // This inturn takes care of the rest.
       obj.mainMethod();
       //Some other child
       obj = new Child2();
       obj.mainMethod();
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: ı tried this but java says it cant find main. Did you tested??

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this.

```
public Parent
{
  public final void run()
  {
    this.runChild
  }

  protected abstract void runChild();
}

public class Child extends Parent
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    run();
  }

  protected void runChild()
  {
    ....
  }
}
```